# Please help with indetifying subformulas in the propositional logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In my textbook of the propositional logic I should indentify all subformulas of the following formula: ¬(a∧b)⟺(c⇒a).

According to the textbook the formula (a∧b)⟺(c⇒a) is not a subformula of the formula ¬(a∧b)⟺(c⇒a). Why?

They also argue that ¬(a∧b)⟺(c⇒a) is a subformula of itself, is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

The formula $\lnot(a \land b) \iff (c \Rightarrow a)$ can be ambiguous if we do not assume a convention about omitting parentheses.

According to the usual convention, the negation symbol applies to as little as possible.

This means that the above formula is an abbreviation for :

> $(\lnot(a \land b)) \iff (c \Rightarrow a)$.

Regarding the second part of the question, the answer is YES: a formula is a sub-formula of itself, as must be evident reviewing the definition of sub-formula in your textbook.

---

*Subformulas* can be "mechanically" generated from the original formula (which is a sub-formula of itself) removing the main connective (there is only one).

Thus, from $(\lnot(a \land b)) \iff (c \Rightarrow a)$ we have to remove $\iff$ to produce two new sub-formulas :

> $\lnot(a \land b)$ and $(c \Rightarrow a)$.

Now we apply the same procedure to $\lnot(a \land b)$ removing the negation sign to produce the new sub-formula $a \land b$ and again to get : $a$ and $b$.

The same for $(c \Rightarrow a)$.

Comment: Than you for your answer. Since English is not my first language I am not sure if you have answered the first question I have asked. It seems to me reasonable to say that  (a∧b)⟺(c⇒a) is a subformula of the formula (¬(a∧b))⟺(c⇒a), but in the textbook they are not arguing that. Why?

Comment: Well I know that I can omit parentheses but my question targets to the symbol for NOT. If this (a AND b) is a subformula for NOT(a AND b), than why (a AND b)IFF(c IMPLY a) is not a subformula of (NOT(a AND b))IFF(c IMPLY a) ?

Comment: The biconditional has higher precedence than the negation.  The formula has a tree structure with the biconditional symbol as the root.$$\lower{4ex}{\neg{\lower{3ex}{\lower{3ex}{(a}\wedge\lower{3ex}{b)}}}}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\lower{4ex}{\lower{3ex}{(a}\Rightarrow\lower{3ex}{c)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If the statement was ¬[(a∧b)⟺(c⇒a)] (i.e. if the statement was the negation of a biconditional), then (a∧b)⟺(c⇒a) would indeed be a subformula. But, the given formula ¬(a∧b)⟺(c⇒a) is a biconditional between ¬(a∧b) and c⇒a. So, those are both subformulas, but (a∧b)⟺(c⇒a) is not

Keep in mind that a subformula is not the same as a substring! Rather, try and understand how the operations are applied to the parts: that will tell you waht the subformulas are.

And yes, any formula is a subformula of itself ... kind of like how every set is a subset of itself.  If we want to exclude the formula itself, we would call for *strict* subformulas.